# How is a custom Sitecore ContentSearch index created?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

As the titles states, how is a custom Sitecore ContentSearch index created? I end up with `[ConfigurationErrorsException: Index has no configuration.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.Initialize() +374` each time I try to add in a custom index.

EDIT:
Looking for a basic sample standalone configuration. Copying / Pasting `sitecore_master_index` or `sitecore_web_index` indexes results in the error.

Comment: What are the steps you executed in order to add a custom index? Have you followed `Sitecore Search and Indexing pdf` from Sitecore SDN? Here is a blog post which might be helpful http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/

Comment: @MarasMusielak The new [pdf](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_search_and_indexing_guide_sc70-usletter.pdf) does not go over a basic configuration. I've copied and pasted the default web index, but I get the error above.

Comment: It would help if you posted the contents of the config file and the name of the config file.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because `sitecore_master_index` and `sitecore_web_index` configuration do not contain `<Configuration>` section.

Add in those indexes definition following node and you should not get this error
`(*Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Core.config, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Master.config,
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config*)`:

```
<Configuration ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration"/>
```

I don't know why it is like that, but it looks like Sitecore's provided index samples do not like it when you try to add your own custom index configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Autohaus on Github](https://github.com/Sitecore/autohaus). Its a custom Sitecore website built by Alex Shyba and Tim Ward. It has a custom index in there to search all the vehicles so you should be able to follow that and see how its done.

On an overview, they have created a new config and referenced the new index name and created an ISearchIndex object using `Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("index_name");`. How are you creating your ISearchIndex object?

Comment: It's not the creation of the ISearchIndex or the SearchContext that errors out, but simply the Index Manager when trying to reindex. That is how I'm grabbing my ISearchIndex though.

Comment: Thanks for the Autohaus link. Forgot about that. Not much of a basic example though. I'll have to post one tonight myself after slimming down theirs. Hope creating an index isn't near that configuration heavy.

Comment: Generally with the Sitecore index features, they favor using config to define the structure so that the code doesn't need to change. I agree the config can be complicated, but its not too bad once you get used to it. It was the same with the Advanced Database Crawler module.

Comment: I reviewed Alex's autohaus site last night - he appears to have modified the predefined index that Sitecore created by adding some new computed fields, field readers, etc.  Is this the new pattern for multi-site support